# Golang Gorilla CEX.IO Websocket authentication error

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm currently trying to connect to the CEX.IO bitcoin exchange's websocket.
Websocket connection is OK but at the time of authentication, I have the error: `Timestamp is not in 20sec range`. I don't know what this error.

Test case 1 & 2 for createSignature is OK (https://cex.io/websocket-api#authentication).

Authentication Go code :

```
func toHmac256(message string, secret string) string {
    key := []byte(secret)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write([]byte(message))
    return strings.ToUpper(hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)))
}

func Signature() (string, string) {
    nonce := time.Now().Unix()  // Edit with Cerise Limón answer
    message := strconv.FormatInt(nonce, 10) + "API-KEY"
    signature := api.toHmac256(message, "SECRET-KEY")
    return signature, nonce
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the timestamp is more than 20 seconds away from the current time.

The API expects time in seconds, not nanoseconds.  Use [Unix](http://godoc.org/time#Time.Unix) to get the time in seconds.

```
     nonce := time.Now().Unix()
```

Unix time is is seconds since Jan 01 1970 UTC.

If this fails, then check that your system time is set correctly down to the second.

Comment: Unix time is seconds since Jan 01 1970 (UTC).  I am asking you to check that the clock on your system is set to within 20 seconds of the correct time.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the timestamp is more than 20 seconds away from the current time.  Your system time must be set correctly to the second.

Comment: You are right ! I update my system time, It's OK. Thank's for your help.